# How do I make some images show under a div with text in it?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm working on a website for someone and I can't get three images to show under a div with text in it for thinner displays. Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="mainText">
        <h1>Header Here</h1>
        <p>Paragraph Here</p>
    </div>

    <ul id="Images">
        <li><img src="IMG1.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
        <li><img src="IMG2.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
        <li><img src="IMG3.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the wide resolution CSS:

```
#mainText {
    width: 40vw;
    margin-left: 8vh;
    margin-right: 0;
    float:left;
}

#mainText h1 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3vh 0;
}

#mainText p {
    color: #ff00ff;
    line-height: 5vh;
}

#Images {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20vw;
}

#Images img {
    width: 20vw;
}
```

And here is the CSS in my media tag for smaller screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #mainText p {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #Images {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `float: none` on the `#mainText` div also

```css
#mainText {
  width: 40vw;
  margin-left: 8vh;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: left;
}

#mainText h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3vh 0;
}

#mainText p {
  color: #ff00ff;
  line-height: 5vh;
}

#Images {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20vw;
}

#Images img {
  width: 20vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #mainText p {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #Images, #mainText {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainText">
  <h1>Header Here</h1>
  <p>Paragraph Here</p>
</div>

<ul id="Images">
  <li><img src="IMG1.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
  <li><img src="IMG2.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
  <li><img src="IMG3.jpg" alt="Screenshot"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to provide a visual description of what you're trying to achieve but hopefully this will help...

If you'd like to 'stack' elements vertically you're likely looking to build a column and drop your elements inside.

```
<div class="my-col">
  ... your code
</div>
```

with CSS defining that new class

```
.my-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```